# ssl error in the hostname

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, tls1.2

Hi I am making a connection to my MQTT server with SSL .I am getting the following exception.

```
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (*.xyz.com) does not match target host name '192.168.2.10'
```

I am using a domain certificate for the ssl. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like HostName verification is enabled while you are trying to make a MQTT connection.
If your HostName verification is enabled, then the Subject DN present in the certificate should be same as the Server Hostname. Here, server is the MQTT broker I guess.

In your case, the system where the broker is running has the HostName '192.168.2.10', whereas the certificate that has been issued to the broker contains some different hostname present in the DN.

Now there can be two solutions to this:

- You can try the same by disabling the hostname verification on the MQTT client end.
- You can issue a new certificate to the broker that contains the Hostname of machine in the Subject DN of the certificate.

Hope it addresses your concern.